# How to retrieve local variables?

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to retrieve a local variable from a programme-function i've run in matlab? i.e. i want to retrieve a variable from the code, which is not appeared in the outputs.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

The following describes code to add to the function itself to make the variable available outside the local scope. When you can't change the function, from the outside there is nothing to be done about changing the scope of course (which is intended, correct behaviour!!).

Dirty ways:

- [global variables](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/global.html)

  ```
  global t
  t=2.468;
  ```
- For scalars, strings, simple values: assign to variables in base workspace using [evalin](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/evalin.html):

  ```
  t=2.468;
  evalin('base', ['var_in_base=' num2str(t) ';']);
  ```
- Any other variable, use [assignin](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/assignin.html):

  ```
  A=magic(20);
  assignin('base','A',A);
  ```

Proper way:

- Inspect them during [debugging](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f10-60570.html)
- If you really want them outside the local scope, add them as output variable!!

Comment: Certainly, but the program needs 1 hour to run because i have many loops, so i'd like to extract some variables i forgot to add as output

Comment: When it's already running now, you'll have to redo it. btw, one hour is pretty short to redo, think twice now about what you want and not want outputted!

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Declare function](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/function.html). You can access local variables if you return them as return values. If you do not, you can't access them from outside.

So in

```
function [mean,stdev] = stat(x)
n = length(x);
mean = sum(x)/n;
stdev = sqrt(sum((x-mean).^2/n));
```

You have access to mean and stdev but there is no way to access n.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know matlab at all, but from programmer's logic
that seems improper and impossible without hacking the code.
That being said, through Google I saw this:

> When you call a script from a function, the script uses the function workspace.
>   Like local functions, nested functions have their own workspaces. However, these workspaces are unique in two significant ways:
>   Nested functions can access and modify variables in the workspaces of the functions that contain them.
>   All of the variables in nested functions or the functions that contain them must be explicitly defined. That is, you cannot call a function or script that assigns values to variables unless those variables already exist in the function workspace.

[Base and Function Workspace](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f0-38052.html)

Not sure if this helps you at all, but it may clarify some points