# Is it possible to instrument matlab functions to automatically compare values of local variables across functions?

Tags: function, matlab, macros

This is related to [How to retrieve local variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003739/how-to-retrieve-local-variables), but broader in scope.

The scenario looks like this. Suppose I have two functions

```
function [OutA OutB OutC] = F1 (x,y,z)
   local1 = x + y - z %some arbitrary computation
   local2 = x - y + z %other computation
end

function [OutA OutB OutC] = F2 (x,y,z)
   local1 = x+ y %some computation
   local2 = x - y %other computation
end
```

I would like to write a function that will take `F1 F2 x y z "local1" "local2"` as inputs, and returns `1` if the `local1` in `F1` matches with the `local2` in `F2` during the execution of each with inputs `x y z`.

Is it possible to do this at all in Matlab, ideally without modification to the original functions? 
I guess related to this is the question of whether functions are first-class objects in Matlab, which I tried to Google for but did not find.

Answer (score 1):

Because the inner variables of a function are private (unless you set them as global or return variables), this is not possible without altering the functions or putting them in a larger function.

The proper way would be to set them as return variables (because of how you use them those local variables *are* actually return variables by definition):

```
function retval = compareLocals(x,y,z)
    [~, ~, ~, local1a, ~] = F1 (x,y,z);
    [~, ~, ~, ~, local2b] = F2 (x,y,z);
    retval = double(local1a=local2b);
end



function [OutA, OutB, OutC, local1, local2] = F1 (x,y,z)
    local1 = x + y - z %some arbitrary computation
    local2 = x - y + z %other computation
end
function [OutA, OutB, OutC, local1, local2] = F2 (x,y,z)
    local1 = x+ y %some computation
    local2 = x - y %other computation
end
```

Or nested functions are also an option (but already hack-ish imo):

```
function retval = compareLocals(x,y,z)
    F1 (x,y,z);
    F2 (x,y,z);
    retval = double(local1a=local2b);


    function [OutA OutB OutC] = F1 (x,y,z)
        local1a = x + y - z %some arbitrary computation
        local2a = x - y + z %other computation
    end

    function [OutA OutB OutC] = F2 (x,y,z)
        local1b = x+ y %some computation
        local2b = x - y %other computation
    end
end
```

and using global variables for this purpose seems just wrong (but then again, the whole idea of [global variables is usually bad practice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable)).